# Is there a map function?

Tags: delphi, collections, delphi-xe2, spring4d

I just wrote this function:

```
class function TGenerics.Map<TFrom, TTo>(const AEnumerable: IEnumerable<TFrom>;
  const AConverter: TConstFunc<TFrom, TTo>): IList<TTo>;
var
  L: IList<TTo>;
begin
  L := TCollections.CreateList<TTo>;
  AEnumerable.ForEach(
    procedure(const AItem: TFrom)
    begin
      L.Add(AConverter(AItem));
    end
  );
  Result := L;
end;
```

This is roughly equivalent to Haskells `map` (or `fmap`, `liftM`, etc).

So I'm wondering does something like this already exist in Spring4D?

Comment: It's really odd that it supports `Where` (Haskell `filter`) but not `Select` (Haskell `map`)

Comment: Just a side note - OmniThreadLibrary has a parallel version of a similar contruct which maps TArray to TArray (http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2015/01/parallel-map.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `TEnumerable.Select<T, TResult>` in `Spring.Collections` (introduced for the not yet released 1.2 - see develop branch).

The reason for `IEnumerable<T>` not having a Select method is that interface types [cannot have parameterized methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/E2535_Interface_methods_must_not_have_parameterized_methods_(Delphi)).

Keep in mind that the implementation in Spring4D is different from yours because it uses streaming and deferred execution.

Comment: I know it's not a perfect (or even correct) solution and all, but I've extended IList with a non-parameterised Select function, which allow you to map to the type of the list. It's often come in handy